# Windows 7 keystrokes to change monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with Windows 7 and the display is dead, no video at all. Therefore, most mouse usage is useless.

I have hooked up the HDMI port to my TV.

Does anybody know how to get the display switched to the HDMI port using keystrokes only?

Comment: Yeah: Windows Key + Shift + Arrow Key. But this is off topic for SO anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another combination:

```
WinKey + P
```

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your laptop, but I believe the command is `Fn+F4`; at least, that's the command on my HP Pavilion Dv4